# auto refreshing page when data in database is changed

Tags: asp.net, sqlcachedependency

my page is using `sqlcachedependency`. so the page read information from cache until data in database is changed but i need the page was auto refresh when data is changed.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the Server knows the data has changed but that there is no active communication with the client until the user hits a button in his browser.

A solution for this could be to write some javascript that would ask the server every X seconds if there are changes. If you want to implement something like this you need to look at AJAX and the [Periodic Refresh](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh) pattern.

Or you could have a look at the new [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) that's being implemented in HTML5 which allows bidirectional communication between client and server.

Comment: thanks.i want to use from timer in ajax but it checked cache every const second.if it's request from cache doesn't decrease the performance of sever?

Comment: Checking every second if there is new data will decrease the performance. You will need to find a delay so bot you're performance and the data integrity are in a reasonable range.